# Find $a$ and $b$ if $f(x)=ax^2+bx$ and $f$ has an inflection point at $(1,-2)$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $a$ and $b$ if $f(x)=ax^2+bx$ and $f$ has an inflection point at $(1,-2)$

I know if extremum was given it would be easy: $f(1)=-2$

$a+b=-2 \Rightarrow f'(1)=2a+b=0$

Result: $b=-4$ and  $a=2$

But for finding second derivative I have a problem..
$$f'(x)=2ax+b$$
$$f''(x)=??$$
I don't know what to do with that $b$???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: So you're asking, what is the derivative of $b$ with respect to $x$ ? $b$ is a constant ...

Comment: but if I treat it as a constant I wont get the same answer of b=-4...and a=2

Comment: Well, strictly speaking, note that all parabolas are either convex or concave; they don't switch that at any point. So with the strictest definition of an inflection point, it doesn't have one (see Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point). Furthermore, the second derivative is always constant (equal to $f''(x) = 2a$), so it doesn't change its sign.

Comment: f''(x)=2a......f''(1)=2a=-2.  so a=-1

Comment: and then how to find b??

Comment: A parabola has no inflection point, only a global maximum or minimum (these  are stationary points, but not points of inflection). The question is phrased wrongly. If we re-interpreted the question accordingly as "stationary point" instead of "inflection point", all you have to do is write $f(1)=-2$ and $f'(1)=0$ which will give you a system of linear simultaneous equations in $a$ and $b$.

Comment: if  the Question is the same...I solved I got an answer of b=-2 and a=0.....plz can u confirm it if it is right??